# How to use the subclass type as return on a method on a super class?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, conventions

So far, the best way I could handle returning the subclass type in the superclass is passing the subclass type as type parameter.

It doesn't look pretty though, so I need to know if there is a better approach to accomplish this.

This is what I have:

```
public abstract class Model<R extends Model<R, ID>, ID extends Serializable> {

    public R find(ID id) {
        return find(getClass(), id);
    }

    ...
}

public final class SampleRecord extends Model<SampleRecord, Long> {

    @Id
    private Long id;

}
```

Comment: No, that's pretty much a canonical pattern in Java.

Comment: This is fine and seen often.  In fact, it is seen so often that C++ hackers have come up with the adorable name “curiously recurring template pattern” for it (or something similar since Java has no such thing as templates).

Comment: It should just be declared as `class Model<R, ID extends Serializable>`. The bound is unnecessary.